# Returning the list with the lowest particular variable in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d, min

I have a task dealing with external text files and lists, and I am having an issue with a specific question, which is as follows:

There is an array of data with the following structure:

```
country, item, cost, quantity
Germany, Air Force One, 90, 12
```

I am required to return the line of the product with the lowest quantity. With a standard list this is very simple using the min() function, however I am having a tough time with the mix between strings and integers, and also the fact that it is in an array. Would I first need to split the list into its various components, find the minimum, and then return the corresponding line? If so how would I return the line corresponding to the min quantity?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a key together with the `min` function like this:

```
s = [["Germany", "Air Force One", 90, 12],["UK", "Air Force One", 900, 11],["USA", "Air Force One", 70, 10]]

print(min(s,key=lambda p: p[3]))
```

The `lambda p: p[3]` means that it will compare the element at index 3, which is the quantity.

Output: `['USA', 'Air Force One', 70, 10]`